# How can redirect the page after the header sent? Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a plugin on wordpress. When the user click the view post button on the home page, It will check some condition to allow or not the user to view the post.

If the user isn't allowed to view the post, page will be redirected to the error page.

But, the problem is that, the plugin is ran by the shortcut, so the function will be ran after the post page loaded. And it come out this error `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/wordpress/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php:237)`

And how do the url redirect after the headers sent?

Also, I need to make it will the shortcut.

Thx a lot.

Here is my code:

```
   function add_post_condition_vpc($atts, $content = null)
    {      

     $userPoint = getPointFromDb();
   if($userPoint > 50)
                  {           

                     //redirect the the page to the view-post-direct-page.php
                     $page_file_temp = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
                     $url= dirname($page_file_temp) . "/view-post-direct-page.php";
                     header("Location: $url ");
                     return "redirect";

                  }
  } 

  add_shortcode('view_post_lmc', 'add_post_condition_vpc');
```

And the share button, I used this code to get the current post url:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Then I add the shortcode on the post.

---

I found a solution.

Here is my code:

```
//redirect the the page to the view-post-direct-page.php
$page_file_temp = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$url= dirname($page_file_temp) . "/view-post-direct-page.php";

$string = '<script type="text/javascript">';
$string .= 'window.location = "' . $url . '"';
$string .= '</script>';

return $string;
```

Use `Javascript` to avoid send the `header again`.

Comment: Use `ob_start();`

Comment: I tried to use `ob_start();`. It is work, but it make me another problem. As I made a `Facebook share button` on the post, and it cannot share the link correctly. The `URL` will be changed to the error page's URL.

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: updated code. thx

Comment: HI @Capslock10 this question may get more attention on [wordpress.se] :)

Answer (score 0):

add this in *functions.php*:

```
function app_output_buffer() {
    ob_start();
} // soi_output_buffer
add_action('init', 'app_output_buffer');
```

Found it here: https://tommcfarlin.com/wp_redirect-headers-already-sent/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a shortcode for this check?

I think you are better of using Wordpress' `init hook`. Add this to functions.php or in your plugin file and the check will be performed before the page is loaded:

```
function add_post_condition_vpc() {      
     $userPoint = getPointFromDb();

     if($userPoint > 50) {           
           $page_file_temp = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
           $url= dirname($page_file_temp) . "/view-post-direct-page.php";
           header("Location: $url ");
           exit(); // just exit, return is not needed here
        }
} 

add_action('init', add_post_condition_vpc);
```

And you could perform a check in this function if the post has some sort of tag attached to it. And when it does you run the userpoint check. This way you won't need a shortcode tag.